# Error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente error al dar clic en un Submit que envió como dato para una consulta SQL:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\multiusuario\admin\buscar.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\multiusuario\admin\buscar.php(12): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\multiusuario\admin\buscar.php on line 12

Y el error es raro, porque como es una consulta select debe tomar los valores que defino, asi que no encuentro que me puede estar causando el error. A continuación, indico el código donde se ejecuta la consulta:

```
<?php
require '../DBconect.php';

if (isset($_POST['Buscar'])) {
    $Buscar = $_POST['Buscar'];
    $sqls = $db->prepare("SELECT nom_comercial,cantidad,precio,fech_caducidad,advertencia,estado,
     DATEDIFF(NOW(), medicamentos.fech_caducidad)*(-1) AS DiasCaducidad 
     FROM medicamentos HAVING DiasCaducidad <= '".$Buscar."'");

    $sqls->bindValue(':search', '%' . $Buscar . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $sqls->execute();

    $result = $sqls->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
?>
```

Y estas serían las líneas de código donde hago la tabla donde se imprimen los datos según la consulta:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Buscador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.12.4-jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
        <h2> Proceso de los Estados </h2>
        <form>
            <div style="float:center; margin-bottom:15px;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead class="thead dark">
                            <th width="15%">Nombre Comercial</th>
                            <th width="10%">Cantidad</th>
                            <th width="13%">Precio</th>
                            <th width="18%">Fecha Caducidad</th>
                            <th width="22%">Advertencia</th>
                            <th width="10%">Estado</th>
                            <th width="15%">Dias de Caducidad</th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            if (isset($result)) {
                                foreach ($result as $row) {
                            ?>

                                    <tr>

                                        <td> <?= $row['nom_comercial'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['cantidad'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['precio'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['fech_caducidad'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['advertencia'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['estado'] ?> </td>
                                        <td> <?= $row['DiasCaducidad'] ?> </td>
                                    </tr>

                            <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
        </form>
        <form>
            <a href="admin_portada.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</button></a>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hecho esto tambien adjunto parte del código de donde se toma la variable "Buscar" del documento admin_portada.php

```html
<form action="buscar.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="Buscar" placeholder="Ingrese el tiempo">
                    <input type="submit" value="Buscar Caducidad">
                </form>
```

Entonces lo que se supone que debe hacer es que cuando yo ingrese en el input un valor de días, es decir 10 o 30 días, al hacer clic en el botón Buscar Caducidad, me envié a una página donde se me muestra una tabla con los datos que coinciden con la búsqueda, o sea, me buscará que alimentos  caducaran en los próximos X días ingresados desde la fecha actual. Pero me da ese error, agradecería su ayuda.

Una cosa mas, cuando ejecuto esa consulta select en MySQL, si me cumple con toda la consulta, pero no en PHP.

Comment: no veo que uses `:search` en tu consulta, lo pones directamente así `HAVING DiasCaducidad <= '".$Buscar."'"` cuando quizás deberias ponerlo así: `HAVING DiasCaducidad <= :search"`

Comment: @masterguru No comprendo, no es lo mismo ponerlo asi, que la variable POST de Buscar?

Comment: No, no es lo mismo.  Si usas `:search` la cadena va a ser escapada correctamente antes de incluirse en la consulta.  Si usas la variable del POST entonces no, y seria susceptible de ataques por Inyección SQL.  Aparte de eso, a efectos de funcionamiento de la consulta seria lo mismo, pero si pones la variable POST de **Buscar** al menos ponla igual que el `:search`, es decir, con los `%` encerrandola, sino la consulta tambien es distinta a lo que haria con el :search.